# Filter on dynamodb table

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a table say location with below struction

**|Location(Hashkey-String)|TimeStamp(Range-Numeric)|#visiting_Person|**

Now I want to get all the visiting persons between two timestamp

```
Table myTable= Table.LoadTable(client, "tableName");
QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter();
filter.AddCondition("TimeStamp", QueryOperator.GreaterThan, 56545454);
Search search = myTable.Query(filter);
```

But it throw errors -

> Query condition missed schema elelment: Location

From error it seems I have to add location (as it is hash key) in filter, but I dont have to filter on a particular location, I have to get any location within timestamp

I tried with setting timestamp as hashkey but I found that we can apply only equal operator on hashkey.

While debugging and changing with some other way i came across with other error i.e. keycondition can not be applied.

---

***Well I am able to do the same with scan, But due to performance I do have to use Query.***

---

Please advise how could i achieve my desired output.

Answer (score 1):

[Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression) requires the primary keys of the table so, there isn't a way to Query just on the Range key.

Basically, since DynamoDB partitions based on hash key and Query operates within a partition, you will need to either:

1. **scan across hash keys** (performance could be improved time-wise with a parallel scan)
2. **structure a hash key that can be used for the query**. E.g. If the range is non-arbitrary you could improve performance by creating an attribute to "bucket" based on some less granular time and building a GSI on it:

   - Suppose the maximum range between the 2 timestamps is 1 day, you could:
   - make an attribute (say "TimeStampDate") that is at date level granularity rather than date+time timestamp granularity.
   - make a GSI with TimeStampDate as the Hash key
   - execute parallel queries on the dates that overlap the queried time range: "TimeStampDate=[start timestamp date] AND TimeStamp BETWEEN [start timestamp / end timestamp]", "TimeStampDate=[start timestamp date + 1 day] AND TimeStamp BETWEEN [start timestamp / end timestamp]", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't work in Cassandra (which follows design of the Dynamo). The logic is that you must specify "any preceding keys", e.g. if you have

```
+---------+---------+--------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   | Value  |
+---------+---------+--------+
| Value 1 | Value 1 |    123 |
| Value 2 | Value 2 |    123 |
| Value 3 | Value 4 |    123 |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

You *must* specify `Col1` before your can filter by `Col2` providing the key is `Col1 and Col2`. In Cassandra `Col1` will indicate on which db server in a cluster ring the record is located, and the `Col2` will be a column key in that table on that particular server. Hope it's now clear as to why its important to have a cluster key specified in the search query.

To solve this you have two options:

- Change your query to pass `Location`
- Add another table that will have only two columns `TimeStamp` and `VisitingPerson`. The idea is that you just duplicate the data, which is fine in a nosql world

Comment: I don't think its a good idea, there must be some way to achieve this, However i can use scan, which i have already done, but i want to use Query, and I am pretty sure there must be some idea

Comment: You get some benefits (like performance at scale) but you have to give up something (like de-normalise data and write to a query specific table). I suspect a scan queries all the nodes in a cluster for the information, which is a no-no with large data volumes.

Comment: Exactly that is the reason why I want to avoid scan.